# Authenticate session with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, next.js, aws-api-gateway, auth0

**Situation**: I have an app (Next.js/React on Vercel) running on *example.com*. I have an api (AWS API Gateway) on *api.example.com*. Currently the application on *example.com* supports login using Auth0 as authentication provider.

**Problem**: I would like to be able to make authenticated requests from the application (*example.com*) to the api (*api.example.com*).

Architecturally, I was hoping for a way for the API Gateway (*api.example.com*) to handle the authenticated session from the app/Auth0 cookie (*example.com*). I thought the browser could share the cookie (since *api.example.com* is trusted) and the API could validate it.

But I don't see a *standard* way to do it. I think I could try to create some custom lambda authorizer for AWS' API Gateway. But since we're dealing with authentication, I would prefer to outsource as much as humanly possible and avoid any custom code. I just can't seem to piece together the way for API Gateway to handle the sessions, which I assumed would be a pretty common problem to solve.

*Sidenote: Previously, I used the pages/api that's baked into Next.js to directly call Lambdas on AWS and expose them. With this, authentication natively works. That's the experience I'm now trying to recreate, but without the user having to take a roundtrip.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to protect APIs it’s better to use JWT tokens to carry over necessary claims e.g. id of authenticated user. OpenID connect and Oauth2.0 are the standards to look into.

Auth0 has documentation of recommended authentication flow: https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow

as well as example with Api Gateway’s HTTP apis: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-aws-http-apis-with-jwt-authorizers/

AWS documentation has more info about Http Apis and JWT token authorizers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html

If your Api gateway is using Rest apis instead of more light-way Http apis then token based Lambda authorizers are the right solution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html